# How to disable errorr message 'print keyword can't be used as identifier in python 2' in pycharm?

Tags: python, python-2.7, pycharm

I am using PyCharm 2018.3.4 (Professional Edition) and I keep getting this error messsage even on simple statements such as

```
print(matching_bids)
```

or

```
print("packed",str(packed))
```

I know this is more of a suggestion, but the only 3 top results in Google talk about this problem, and there is an [unanswered question about this in the  jetbrains forum](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/360000511299--print-keyword-can-t-be-used-as-identifier-in-Python-2). Hence, I have no idea what to do about this error, because it cannot be a syntax error. I am not able to disable it from the inspections either, and cannot disable 'All Inspections' just for this and write more erroneous code without pertinent warnings.

Even if I create a new .py file and just enter

```
print("hi")
```

it still shows this error.

[image: scshot]

I am using 3.7 python with a django ver 2.0.1

Update:
This is my project interpreter:

[image: s]

Comment: Seems like your project interpreter is not setup properly.  Check your preferences

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out by [@rdas](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2947378/rdas) in comments. Please make sure you have set Python 3 as your project interpreter.

Reference : https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/configuring-python-interpreter.html

Answer (score -1):

Based on the update of your post, to just disable the error do this:

1. Go To File > Settings > Editor > Inspections
2. Search for "identifier"
3. Disable "Correctness of identifier reference"

I do not recommend this but if you see no other way to solve this issue this is a temporary fix.

Comment: Guess what ? I already did replace that. It still shows up. I disabled a bunch of options to no avail.

Comment: @RohitKumar Is "Code compatibility inspection" disabled in Inspections? If not try that.

Comment: Just did that, it was a warning, not an error. Nevertheless, I disabled that too but print error remains.

Comment: Any reason you can't use the latest PyCharm?

Comment: I just updated my pycharm to latest, and this error still persists. You do not need to post so many answers wishing one maybe the correct one. Also, version should not have mattered at all.